# python email module for Gmail / subject

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I' m parsing emails in an mbox format with the email module. The email arrived from Gmail.

The important part of the code is:

```
import email

email_content = sys.stdin.read()
email_obj = email.message_from_string(email_content)
subject = email_obj['subject']
```

.

For the subject i' m getting a bit weird encoding. In the raw text it looks like:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?MjAxOS4gw6FwcmlsaXMgMjUu?=
```

. Can anybody tell me how is it encoded and how do i "extract" it?

Many thanks.

Python: 2.7.13

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject has been encoded according to RFC 2047. This is because an email subject is a header tag, and header tags must be ascii.

To decode:

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> decode_header("Subject: =?UTF-8?B?MjAxOS4gw6FwcmlsaXMgMjUu?=")
[('Subject:', None), ('2019. \xc3\xa1prilis 25.', 'utf-8')]
```

The escaped bytes in the tuple decode as follows:

```
'2019. április 25.'
```

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for this.